# Circular Transition, change initial circle size

Tags: ios, swift

I have a circular transition you can find in the code below. This transition creates an extending circle with the next view controller inside.

It works fine, but I've been trying to increase the circle size on start for a while now.

To be exact, currently on execution the circle will be drawn from zero, but I want it to have an initial size which appears immediately, from where it starts extending.

**How can I change the initial size of the circle?**

```
import UIKit

class CircularTransition: NSObject {

    var circle = UIView()

    var startingPoint = CGPoint.zero {
        didSet {
            circle.center = startingPoint
        }
    }

    var circleColor = UIColor.white

    var duration = 0.2

    enum CircularTransitionMode:Int {
        case present, dismiss, pop
    }

    var transitionMode:CircularTransitionMode = .present

}

extension CircularTransition:UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

        if transitionMode == .present {
            if let presentedView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to) {
                let viewCenter = presentedView.center
                let viewSize = presentedView.frame.size

                circle = UIView()

                circle.frame = frameForCircle(withViewCenter: viewCenter, size: viewSize, startPoint: startingPoint)

                circle.layer.cornerRadius = circle.frame.size.height / 2
                circle.center = startingPoint
                circle.backgroundColor = circleColor
                circle.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.001, y: 0.001)
                containerView.addSubview(circle)


                presentedView.center = startingPoint
                presentedView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.001, y: 0.001)
                presentedView.alpha = 0
                containerView.addSubview(presentedView)

                UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                    self.circle.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                    presentedView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                    presentedView.alpha = 1
                    presentedView.center = viewCenter

                }, completion: { (success:Bool) in
                    transitionContext.completeTransition(success)
                })
            }

        }else{
            let transitionModeKey = (transitionMode == .pop) ? UITransitionContextViewKey.to : UITransitionContextViewKey.from

            if let returningView = transitionContext.view(forKey: transitionModeKey) {
                let viewCenter = returningView.center
                let viewSize = returningView.frame.size


                circle.frame = frameForCircle(withViewCenter: viewCenter, size: viewSize, startPoint: startingPoint)

                circle.layer.cornerRadius = circle.frame.size.height / 2
                circle.center = startingPoint

                UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                    self.circle.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.001, y: 0.001)
                    returningView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.001, y: 0.001)
                    returningView.center = self.startingPoint
                    returningView.alpha = 0

                    if self.transitionMode == .pop {
                        containerView.insertSubview(returningView, belowSubview: returningView)
                        containerView.insertSubview(self.circle, belowSubview: returningView)
                    }


                }, completion: { (success:Bool) in
                    returningView.center = viewCenter
                    returningView.removeFromSuperview()

                    self.circle.removeFromSuperview()

                    transitionContext.completeTransition(success)

                })

            }


        }

    }



    func frameForCircle (withViewCenter viewCenter:CGPoint, size viewSize:CGSize, startPoint:CGPoint) -> CGRect {
        let xLength = fmax(startPoint.x, viewSize.width - startPoint.x)
        let yLength = fmax(startPoint.y, viewSize.height - startPoint.y)

        let offestVector = sqrt(xLength * xLength + yLength * yLength) * 2
        let size = CGSize(width: offestVector, height: offestVector)

        return CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)

    }

}
```